# Rewrite a piece of php code for copy file to folder

Tags: php, zip

This is simple php code, but I'm an asp developer.

Can anybody rewrite this piece of code, so instead of compressing files into zip format, it just copies them in, for example, a 'wwwroot' folder?

```
<?php

/* CONFIG */

$pathToAssets = array("elements/bootstrap", "elements/css", "elements/fonts", "elements/images", "elements/js");

$filename = "tmp/website.zip"; //use the /tmp folder to circumvent any permission issues on the root folder

/* END CONFIG */


$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);


//add folder structure

foreach( $pathToAssets as $thePath ) {

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $thePath ),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {

        if( $file->getFilename() != '.' && $file->getFilename() != '..' ) {

            // Get real path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();

            $temp = explode("/", $name);

            array_shift( $temp );

            $newName = implode("/", $temp);

            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $newName);

        }

    }

}



foreach( $_POST['pages'] as $page=>$content ) {

    $zip->addFromString($page.".html", $_POST['doctype']."\n".stripslashes($content));

    //echo $content;

}

//$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
//$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");

$zip->close();


$yourfile = $filename;

$file_name = basename($yourfile);

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($yourfile));

readfile($yourfile);

unlink('website.zip');

exit;?>
```

Besides, if you can, please uncompress the files to the destination folder and delete the original zip file once it's finished.

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to help with _specific issues_ you encounter _in your own code_. So start out yourself, if you run into serious issues, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and point out that issue you ran into.

Comment: If you really look for someone to do your work for you, then I suggest you hire a payed programmer.

Comment: tanx for response but i don't like php and i don't want use it on my work some Friend aske me a favor so i'm posting that issue

Comment: With respect you can ignore it

Comment: Please read about how this site works and why those rules have been agreed upon. It appears you are not aware of that.

Comment: Maybe you are write about some facts i think the base of this site for developer specially new once like me fore making help not that argue to eche other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132622/discussion-between-pooria-shariatzadeh-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1):

See [copy](http://php.net/copy).

Replace this:

```
        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $newName);
```

to this:

```
        copy($filePath, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/' . $name);
```

Comment: tanx for helping me on this but it not  working i also read copy but the fact That i can note debug php is annoying me